# reading string as variable

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs3

```
function setUploadedAudioStream(index, audio_file_metadata) {
  if (route.params.id) {
    audio_file_metadata.value.children[0].innerHTML = `<div><audio src=${URL.createObjectURL(
      filesData.value[index]
    )} controls="true" crossorigin="anonymous"></audio></div>`;
 
  }
```

I am reciving string from audio_file_metadata , which I have as a varaible defined. how do
I access it as a variable

Comment: have you tried using the eval() function?

Comment: and document of `eval` : https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/eval